# How to fix Page not found (404) error django2.0 for profile pages

Tags: python, django

How to fix Page not found (404) error django2.0 for profile pages

this code

**views code**

'''

```
def profile(request, slug):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)

    context = {

        'profile':profile,
    }

    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html' ,context)
```

'''
and this 
urls.py

'''

```
from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView,logout #login 

app_name='accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.home, name ='home'),
    # path(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name':'registration/login.html'}),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    # path(r'^signup/$', views.register, name='register'),
    path('signup/', views.register, name='signup'),
    path(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
     # path(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),

]

'''
```

profile.html page in templates /registration folder

Comment: Please include the complete error when you ask a question. At the moment we can't tell which URL is giving you the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `path()` then you shouldn't use regexes like `r'^logout/$'` and `r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$`.

Replace the following two URL patterns

```
path(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
path(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

with these:

```
path('logout/', logout, name='logout'),
path('<slug:slug>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem